# Ошибка при публикации ASP.NET Core на IIS Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis

Всем привет. Пытаюсь опубликовать ASP.NET Core проект на IIS Server, но получаю ошибку в итоге:

```
Модуль         IIS Web Core
Уведомление    неизвестно
Обработчик     Пока не определено
Код ошибки     0x8007000d
```

И что еще заметил. На компьютере установлен Asp.Net Core. Но в модулях IIS Server он не отображается. Т.е. почему IIS Server не видит модуль AspNetCoreModule?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Проверьте в файле на IIS сервере ApplicationHost.config этого элемента:          <section name="aspNetCore" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />

Comment: Проверил. Данная строка имеется